# PerfTrack to measure system responsiveness to user actions in Windows

Tags: windows-7, benchmarking

Is Perftrack mentioned [here](http://channel9.msdn.com/posts/Charles/Inside-Windows-7-Reliability-Performance-and-PerfTrack/) just used internally at Microsoft ? Are they any similar benchmark programs ?

Comment: Looks interesting, but no PerfTrack executable on my Windows 7 machine.

Comment: Me too, but I'll be really interested as  it relates to system responsiveness to user actions ...and building that sort of tool is only possible if you make the OS or know its internals(Mark Russinovich fans?)  what are such tools on Linux?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Short answer yes. It is a dll that runs in the background and to be used by Microsoft. Maybe at some point benchmark software will be able to utilise this DLL but right now you only have you bog standard bench mark programs

Comment: dll which runs in the background?? is this a service or a job ? if its a dll then which API exposes it? is this part of the undocumented APIs?

Comment: PerfTrack is an event provider registered with the Event Tracing for Windows (ETW) system. Windows ships with a command line tool to start, stop, and dump those events (i can't remember the name of it). What you really want is `xperf` (part of the Microsoft Windows Performance Toolkit, which ships with the Windows SDK). The ETW infrastructure is docuented, and `PerfTrack` is just another provider in that system. And using published and supported tools you can see those events yourself. But there are different ETW providers that give more useful data.

Comment: Found it: `>logman.exe`